# how to make cameraOverlayView along the y axis (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, cameraoverlayview

I am making a photo app that I want the imagePicker screen to have blocks of red to pre mask the photo before it crops. My following code gets a roadblock on the top x axis. I would like to place another red box along the entire y axis where the yellow rectangle is.

```
    let blockView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 150))

           blockView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = blockView
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following :

```
let mainView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height-150))

let blockView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 150))
blockView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

let blockView1 = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 170, width: 100, height: self.view.frame.size.height-320))
blockView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

mainView.addSubview(blockView)
mainView.addSubview(blockView1)

imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = mainView
```

Comment: How can I get it on all 4 sides. Right now it works great but its only on two sides.

Comment: `let blockView2 = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: self.view.frame.size.width-110, y: 170, width: 100, height: self.view.frame.size.height-320))
blockView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow mainView.addSubview(blockView2)` You can add one more view like this